# Reading AWS DynamoDb records from Apche Spark always returns empty dataset

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I'm following [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/apache-spark-with-dynamodb-use-cases-a541c2afcc95) and I want to read data from dynamodb in my spark job.

The problem is that dataset which I read from dynamo db is always empty.

I know that because this statment: `System.out.println("Citations count: " + citations.count());` prints zero, but table itself is not empty. It contains 12,801 items.  I checked that in aws console.

Here is my code :

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.lcarvalho.sparkddb.config.SparkConfiguration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class Covid19CitationsWordCount {

    private static final String APP_NAME = "Covid19CitationsWordCount";
    private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Covid19CitationsWordCount.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        // Building the Spark session
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = SparkConfiguration.buildSparkContext(APP_NAME);
        JobConf jobConf = SparkConfiguration.buildJobConf(sparkContext, Boolean.FALSE);
        // Building a RDD pointing to the DynamoDB table
        JavaPairRDD<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> citations =
            sparkContext.hadoopRDD(jobConf, DynamoDBInputFormat.class, Text.class, DynamoDBItemWritable.class);
        System.out.println("Citations count: " + citations.count());

        // Filtering citations published in 2020
        JavaPairRDD<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> filteredCitations = citations.filter(citation -> {
            DynamoDBItemWritable item = citation._2();
            Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = item.getItem();
            return attributes.get("publishedYear") == null ? Boolean.FALSE : attributes.get("publishedYear").getN().equals("2020");
        });
        System.out.println("Filtered citations count: " + filteredCitations.count());

        // Building a RDD with the citations titles
        JavaRDD citationsTitles = filteredCitations.map(citation -> {
            DynamoDBItemWritable item = citation._2();
            Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = item.getItem();
            return attributes.get("title").getS();
        });

        // Building a RDD with the citations titles words
        JavaRDD<String> citationsTitlesWords = citationsTitles.flatMap(citationTitle -> Arrays
            .asList(citationTitle.toString().split(" ")).iterator());
        System.out.println("Citations titles word count: " + citationsTitlesWords.count());

        // Counting the number of times each word was used
        Map<String, Long> wordCounts = citationsTitlesWords.countByValue();
        System.out.println("Citations titles distinct word count: " + wordCounts.size());

        for (String word : wordCounts.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Word: " + word + " - Count: " + wordCounts.get(word));
        }
    }
}


import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class SparkConfiguration {

    public static JobConf buildJobConf(JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext, final boolean useDefaultAWSCredentials) {

        final JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration());
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.servicename", "dynamodb");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "Covid19Citation");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "Covid19Citation");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
        jobConf.set("dynamodb.regionid", "us-east-1");
        jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat");
        jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat");

        if (useDefaultAWSCredentials) {
            DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
            jobConf.set("dynamodb.awsAccessKeyId", defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
            jobConf.set("dynamodb.awsSecretAccessKey", defaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());
        }
        return jobConf;
    }

    public static JavaSparkContext buildSparkContext(String application) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(application)
                .registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
                        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"),
                        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable")
                });
        return new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }

    public static JavaSparkContext buildLocalSparkContext(String application) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .setAppName(application)
                .registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
                    Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"),
                    Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable")
                });
        return new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

1. I double checked table name, and the table name is correct.
2. I checked privileges which user with provided awsAccessKeyId, and awsSecretAccesKey has, and it has full admin privilege.

I don't have any more ideas how to troubleshoot this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note** : Spark job finishes without any errors, and here is how stdout log looks like:

```
Citations count: 0
Filtered citations count: 0
Citations titles word count: 0
Citations titles distinct word count: 0
```

This is stderr log:

```
23/06/11 22:07:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/06/11 22:07:02 WARN DependencyUtils: Skip remote jar s3://sitemapgenerationscheduledjob/jars/Covid19CitationsWordCount-1.0.jar.
23/06/11 22:07:02 INFO DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal/172.31.11.132:8032
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (12288 MB per container)
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 2432 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
23/06/11 22:07:03 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
23/06/11 22:07:03 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
23/06/11 22:07:06 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-478c0486-9bbc-413f-896a-13839434207e/__spark_libs__4221092772806684590.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1686521110686_0001/__spark_libs__4221092772806684590.zip
23/06/11 22:07:07 INFO Client: Uploading resource s3://sitemapgenerationscheduledjob/jars/Covid19CitationsWordCount-1.0.jar -> hdfs://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1686521110686_0001/Covid19CitationsWordCount-1.0.jar
23/06/11 22:07:07 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://sitemapgenerationscheduledjob/jars/Covid19CitationsWordCount-1.0.jar' for reading
23/06/11 22:07:09 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/etc/hudi/conf.dist/hudi-defaults.conf -> hdfs://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1686521110686_0001/hudi-defaults.conf
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-478c0486-9bbc-413f-896a-13839434207e/__spark_conf__4224384365241794246.zip -> hdfs://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1686521110686_0001/__spark_conf__.zip
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1686521110686_0001 to ResourceManager
23/06/11 22:07:10 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1686521110686_0001
23/06/11 22:07:11 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:11 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1686521230409
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1686521110686_0001/
     user: hadoop
23/06/11 22:07:12 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:13 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:14 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:15 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:17 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:18 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
23/06/11 22:07:19 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: RUNNING)
23/06/11 22:07:19 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-172-31-5-161.ec2.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 41187
     queue: default
     start time: 1686521230409
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1686521110686_0001/
     user: hadoop
23/06/11 22:07:20 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: RUNNING)
23/06/11 22:07:21 INFO Client: Application report for application_1686521110686_0001 (state: FINISHED)
23/06/11 22:07:21 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-172-31-5-161.ec2.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 41187
     queue: default
     start time: 1686521230409
     final status: SUCCEEDED
     tracking URL: http://ip-172-31-11-132.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1686521110686_0001/
     user: hadoop
23/06/11 22:07:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/06/11 22:07:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-478c0486-9bbc-413f-896a-13839434207e
23/06/11 22:07:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-bdd3e76a-21a7-4b42-a853-3523f5233ace
Command exiting with ret '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, until I discovered today the release notes of Amazon EMR:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-680-release.html

It states under the known issues:

> When you use the DynamoDB connector with Spark on Amazon EMR versions 6.6.0, 6.7.0, and 6.8.0, all reads from your table return an empty result, even though the input split references non-empty data. This is because Spark 3.2.0 sets `spark.hadoopRDD.ignoreEmptySplits` to `true` by default. As a workaround, explicitly set `spark.hadoopRDD.ignoreEmptySplits` to `false`. Amazon EMR release 6.9.0 fixes this issue.

If you are on EMR, check your version and set the config value.